# Solving a linear multivariable recurrrence

Tags: recurrence-relations

How do I solve a linear multivariable recurrence relation like the following:
$$
f(x, y) = a f(x - 1, y) + b f(y - 1, x) + c
$$
subject to the boundary conditions:
$$
f(x, 0) = 0, f(0, y) = 1
$$
Assuming $a, b, c$ are all real (possible negative).

I'm not even sure it's possible to do, so if that's true I'd like to know that as well.

Comment: Is $bf(y-1,x)$ written intentionally or is it supposed to be $bf(x,y-1)$?

Comment: Yeah it looks weird, but it's correct the way I've written it.